# String.split not operating as expected

Tags: java, string, split, token

So I'm trying to split a string

```
String[] tokens = coded_string.split("\\)|\\(|\\,|\\s+");
```

so if the coded string is `students = load(classlist.csv)`
all tokens are fine

```
token[0] = "students"
token[1] = "="
token[2] = "load"
token[3] = "classlist.csv"
```

but when the string `students = load ( classlist.csv )` spaces between brackets i get empty tokens why is that and how can i fix it?

```
token[0] = "students"
token[1] = "="
token[2] = "load"
token[3] = ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have two delimiters in a row, an empty space followed by an open paren, it returns a match on the 'nothing' that is between them as an empty string.  You could use a character class instead of alternation to match entire blocks of potential delimiter characters.  You haven't stated your actual requirements, so it's tough to know if that would be strictly correct for all inputs.

```
String[] tokens = coded_string.split("[)(,\\s]+");
```

Comment: It works i would upvote you but i don't have the reputation, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`coded_string.split("(\\)|\\(|\\s+)+")`will work fine

Comment: not when you have two delimiters in a row like Affe mentions it creates a blank token which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: The '+' in the end concatenates delimiters, so you get no empty tokens.